# TypeScript type narrowing for class comparison

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have a function where I need to pass in **both** a class and a function that will return an instance of that class. As the class could be one of many (in the example below Person or Animal), I'm using a generic type T extends typeof Person | typeof Animal.

The idea is then to do type checks to internally handle the different cases (Person or Animal):

```
class Person {}
class Animal {}

function doSomething<T extends typeof Person | typeof Animal>(clazz: T, getObject: () => InstanceType<T>) {
    if(clazz === Person) {
        clazz   // clazz: T extends typeof Person | typeof Animal. Desired would be typeof Person

        const obj = getObject()     // obj: InstanceType<T>. Desired would be Person
        const newObj = new clazz()  // newObj: Person | Animal. Desired would be Person
    }
    else if(clazz === Animal) { /*...*/ }
}
```

I'm a bit confused why TypeScript doesn't even narrow the type of clazz to Person given clazz === Person.
Is there anything obvious that I'm missing or any other way that I could design the method **signature** such that type narrowing down to Person would work for the above example?

PS: The body of the function will be provided by a user of my application and getObject is a relatively expensive operation; therefore a check like obj instanceof Person is not desirable.

Any inputs to make this work are very welcome. And generally I'd much rather have higher complexity in the method signature for a simpler method body (without need for casting to Person).

Comment: It doesn't narrow because testing *values* cannot narrow a generic type *parameter*; it's possible that `T` is still equal to `typeof Person | typeof Animal`, say if you call it with `doSomething(Math.random()<0.5 ? Person : Animal, () => Math.random()<0.5 ? new Person() : new Animal())`, so the check doesn't do much.  Personally I'd rather see you pass in some sort of discriminated union to `doSomething()` and narrow based on that, if you care about `if`/`else` narrowing. But it's a sizable refactor, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mbGRBW). Does that meet your needs? If so I can write it up.

Comment: Thank you very much @jcalz, I was able to solve it quite well with your approach. Now I'm providing one parameter of type { type: 'Person', getObject: () => Person } | { type: 'Animal', getObject: () => Animal }.
Please feel free to post your solution as an answer so that I can mark it as the accepted answer and you get the credit :-)